# A convergence question in $L^2$ construction of Brownian motion

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, hilbert-spaces, brownian-motion

I feel confused with a **particular** step in the $L^2$ consturction of Brownian motion.

Let $\{\xi_n \sim N(0,1)\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d Gaussian random variables on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Consider a Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$ equipped with the conventional Lebesgue inner product. Let $\{\phi_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a complete orthonormal system in this $L^2$.

Define

$$
W_N(t) = \sum^N_{n=1}\xi_n \langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t)}, \phi_n\rangle_{L^2}
$$

as approxiamtion to Brownian motion. I have a question in a particular proof showing that the limit $\lim_{N\to\infty} W_N$ exists in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$. The Lemma 3.1 of the book by [Rene Schilling and Lothar Partzsch (2012)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110307306.20/pdf) shows that

$$
\mathbb{E}[(W_N(t))^2] = \sum^N_{n=1}\langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t)}, \phi_n\rangle^2_{L^2} \quad \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} t<\infty \quad \text{by Parseval's identity}
$$

Then under the limit, **the authors say that $W(t) = L^2-\lim_{N\to\infty} W_N(t)$ exists. I don't understand how this is concluded immediately**. Essentially you are taking a limit of an $L^2(\mathbb{P})$-norm. How does $\lim_{N\to\infty} \lVert W_N(t) \rVert <\infty$ imply the sequence $\{W_N(t)\}$ has a limit in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$? Am I missing some obviouse facts that I did not see?

---

Then I tried to show the limit by showing that $\{W_N(t)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, since $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ is complete.

So, by some algebras

$$
\lim_{M\to\infty} \sup_{N\geq M} \mathbb{E}[(W_N(t) - W_M(t))^2] = \lim_{M\to\infty} \sup_{N\geq M}\sum^N_{k=M+1}\langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t)}, \phi_k\rangle_{L^2}^2
$$

How do I continue from here? I can see that

$$
\sum^N_{k=M+1}\langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t)}, \phi_k\rangle_{L^2}^2 < \sum^\infty_{k=M+1}\langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t)}, \phi_k\rangle_{L^2}^2
$$

**But what does $ \lim_{M\to\infty} \sum^\infty_{k=M+1}\langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t)}, \phi_k\rangle_{L^2}^2 $ mean? Does it equal to zero?**

**As a conclusion, the above bold sentences are my two questions.**

Comment: The last limit equals to 0 since it is a limit of a tail of the convergent series (the sum of squared coordinates of $1_{[0,t)}$ in the basis $\{\phi_k\}$).

Comment: @FedorPetrov ah yes, true. Thanks.